# Statistically insignificant correlation vs. correlation of 0?

Tags: statistics

I am having trouble isolating these two concepts.

If the correlation, using Pearson’s r, is 0 and statistically significant then we can conclude the data are not linearly related - there is no correlation.

If the correlation, whatever it may be, is statistically insignificant then we fail to reject the null hypothesis that the population correlation is 0. So essentially we are saying the population correlation is 0.

How are these two observation different?

Comment: Choosing $r=0$ or $r \neq 0$ as null in your hypothesis testing makes a strong difference, if this is what you're asking

Comment: Well I’m using Excel ANOVA regression. I assume they use null of r=0, yes?

Answer (score 0):

"then we fail to reject the null hypothesis that the population correlation is 0. So essentially we are saying the population correlation is 0."

You might also fail to reject the hypothesis that the population correlation is 0.729.

If you fail to reject the claim that there is \$100000000 hidden somewhere in your house, then you're saying there IS \$100000000 in your house?

Huh?  Really?!?!

Comment: I’m confused David! Scared alone and confused.

Comment: So essentially it means we just don’t know what the correlation is from our analysis???

Comment: "Fail to reject the null" means you do not have enough evidence to say otherwise.

Comment: So you are essentially left with nothing if you have a high p value? The correlation you came up with cannot be considered a good estimate of the actual correlation?